# Bootstrap image asset not processed for props style attribute on Vue Component (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, asset-pipeline, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have been trying to import an image asset relative path to a banner component. The following works just fine.

```html
<b-img src="~/static/images/carousel1.jpg" alt="Samyojya Consultants banner"/>
```

On html, I see it rendered as this

```html
<div class="card-body"><img src="/_nuxt/static/images/carousel1.jpg"...
```

But the **v-bind** style representation like this does not bundle the image

```html
<b-img :src="imgSrc" :alt="title+'banner'"/>
```

I can see on the html that *imgSrc* value is passing on but not compiled by asset processor

```html
<div class="card-body"><img src="~/static/images/carousel1.jpg" ...
```

Is there a way we can explicitly trigger this compilation? *require* doesn't seem to work too.

```html
<b-img :src="require(imgSrc)" :alt="require(title)+'banner'"/>
```

This dynamic style is needed for my use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the calling (parent) template, I used this

```html
<banner :imgSrc="imgSrc" ...
```

And the data export in parent like this.

```js
export default {
  data: function(){
    return {
      imgSrc:require('../static/images/carousel2.jpg')
    }
  },
...
```

In the child component where the banner is drawn.

```html
<b-img :src="imgSrc"...
```

**Note:** require needs a relative path (../static) from components/pages while without require we can use absolute (~/static).

Comment: Props should be `:img-src` and not `:imgSrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed prop (or method, or similar) to resolve (require) the relative path:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Image title'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    imgSrc() {
      // Relative to component directory
      return require('./image.png')
    }
  }
}
```

And then reference that in your template:

```html
<b-img :src="imgSrc" :alt="title+' banner'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<b-img :src="require('../static/images/carousel1.jpg')" alt="Samyojya Consultants banner"/>
```

Comment: Yes. This works similar to _src="../static/images/carousel1.jpg"_ . The challenge here is to take it through a prop variable like so _:src="require(imgSrc)"_ doesn't work! It looks so simple but tricky!

Comment: Also, I tried placing require at parent component (which is calling the banner component) like this _<banner imgSrc="require(''../static/images/carousel1.jpg'')"..._ Doesn't seem to work!